# initializing variables in ActiveRecord's classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How to initialize variables in ActiveRecord class? 
Variables here is the variables that are outside the scope of database

such as:

```
class Product
  attr_accessor :used
end
```

I want to initially assign `@used` initially to `false`, later if some person access the product, i will change `@used` to `true`

First i thought of putting `@used=false` in initialize method, but it does not get called.

Comment: If you really want a falsy value, then you don't need any initialization. false and nil are both falsy values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
attr_accessor_with_default :used, false
```

Or if you want to use initialize approach you can define callback after_initialize

```
def after_initialize
  @used = false
end
```

Using `attr_accessor_with_default` with an object literal (e.g. `attr_accessor_with_default :used, false`) is unsafe to use with any mutable objects. Specifically, it means that different instances of your class will have the *same* object as their default value. This is sort of like trying to use a class variable (`@@my_var`) where you want an instance variable (`@my_var`). If you want to use a mutable object (e.g. a `String`, `Array`, or `Hash`), you must use the block syntax:

```
attr_accessor_with_default(:used) { Array.new }
```

Comment: the first one does not work correctly. if the default value is Array.new, i wonder why?

attr_accessor_with_default :some_val, Array.new

and the 2nd one works perfectly, thank you

Comment: Remember attr_accessor_with_default uses the value. Array.new is a simple value, and the reference is copied. I suspect attr_accessor_with_default accepts a block for such a case. It does: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#M000043

Answer (score 1):

Define a method called :after_initialize

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def after_initialize
    @used = false
  end
end
```

It will be called (ahem) after the initialize method

Hope this helps